# How to close cmd window from vim command after using latexmk?

Tags: windows, vim, latex

I am new to vim and I'm using it to type up my `latex` documents. I work on Windows, and have defined this map in my vimrc file:

```
autocmd FileType tex inoremap ,lc <Esc>:w! \| !latexmk -pdf -pv %<CR>
```

When latexmk is ran, it opens up a cmd window and then the PDF viewer window. However, it doesn't close the cmd window, which I then have to close by pressing any key. Is there any way to define my map such that it closes the command line and opens up my PDF? I thought something like

```
autocmd FileType tex inoremap ,lc <Esc>:w! \| !latexmk -pdf %<CR> \| !latexmk -pv %<CR>
```

could work, but turns out it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
autocmd FileType tex inoremap ,lc <Esc>:w! \| !latexmk -pdf -pv %<CR> \| call feedkeys(' ')<CR>
```

The `feedkeys()` simulates the press of the given key(s), in occurence the space key, which should close the command message for you.

---

#### Additional advices

As you are new to Vim, you may be interested by some additional advices I want to share to improve your above code:

- You can add the `<buffer>` argument to your mapping:

  ```
  autocmd FileType tex inoremap <buffer> ,lc   ...
  ```

  It will map your shortkey *only* for latex buffers. Without it, once a latex file is loaded, every buffer and window will interpret your mapping, which is not what you want I guess.
- You can create a dedicated function in order to perform the job you want: it will improve readability and make it easier to modify. Indeed, your autocommand line is becoming quite long to read, and it might be still longer if you wanted to add more features.

  So you could transform your code into something like this:

  ```
  autocmd FileType tex inoremap <buffer> ,lc <Esc>:call MakeLatex()<CR>

  function MakeLatex()
      w!
      !latexmk -pdf -pv %
      call feedkeys(' ')
  endf
  ```
- Depending of what exact behaviour you want for your mapping, you could replace `<esc>` by `<c-o>` in your mapping.

  This way, you can stay in Insert mode after having typed your shortcut:

  ```
  autocmd FileType tex inoremap <buffer> ,lc <C-O>:call MakeLatex()<CR>
  ```
- The last thing to improve (imho) would be to put all of this into a separate ftplugin file. This way you can separate features that you only want for Latex files, and make it easier to add even more filetype-based features.

  In order to do this, go to your vim home directory (it should be something like `~/.vim` or `~/vimfiles` on Windows) and create the file `<YOUR_VIM_DIR>/ftplugin/tex.vim`; this file will be loaded each time you will want to edit a latex file, without the need of any `autocmd FileType tex`. Then put the following code into this file:

  ```
  inoremap <buffer> ,lc <c-o>:MakeLatex<cr>

  command! -buffer MakeLatex call s:make_latex()

  function s:make_latex()
      w!
      !latexmk -pdf -pv %
      call feedkeys(' ')
  endf
  ```

  It is a *slightly* improved version compared to the above one, because now, *everything* is local to the buffer or to the script. In the previous version, the `MakeLatex()` function scope was global to Vim, while it was not needed outside of Latex files. With this version, `s:make_latex()` is local to the script, and the `MakeLatex` command is local to the buffer, so the scope of commands/functions is really limited to Latex files only.

Hope this can be useful, happy vimming;

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer. I have used your code but the cmd window doesn't shut down. I think it's because my vim window opens a cmd window, which then opens the viewer and thus the order to type the space key gets lost. Does that make sense? If not, what could be happening?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read well enough your question, I was wrong about what you mean with "cmd window" (linux user there). So my answer is useless for your problem, good luck

Comment: No problem, thanks for your additional advices, though, they seem pretty neat.